# Set Width and Height As 100% For an Edit Control

Tags: c, winapi, dynamic, controls

How do I make an Edit Control have its width and height as 100% of the window.

A good example of this is the Edit Control in Notepad.

Up till now, I've been setting the size of controls in the CreateWindow() function as static integers.

e.g.

```
CreateWindow("EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    0, 0, 640, 480, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I am using C and Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle `WM_SIZE` messages in your main window procedure and use `SetWindowPos` API call to resize an edit control.